# creating a grouped barplot in r that does'nt use counts

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to create a barplot with the following data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xthu6aupp8c7ox/codeexampl.PNG?dl=0

I want the x-axis to show the elements (Sc, Y, La...) and for every element I want two bars next to each other. One for X13608g and one for X13608f with 48.3235 and 53.9796 as the y values. I can get it to work with one bar but as soon as I try to add a second bar r calculates the counts for each value of X13608g and X13608f and displays the counts on the y-axis instead of the actual values.

I tried it using the barplot function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you show the output of the `dput(df)` command (`df` is supposed to be the name of your data set)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do with the package ggplot2.

You need `stat="identity"` to plot the actual values and not the counts. You need `position="dodge"` to put the bars side by side.

(I did a fake data.frame with fake numbers (`df`) but you can put yours instead)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(12345) # needed just for the runif example
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(abs(runif(10)), 5, 2))
colnames(df) <- c("X13608g", "X13608f")
df$element <- c("Sc", "y", "La", "Ce", "Pr")
melted.df <- melt(df, id.vars="element")
ggplot(data=melted.df, aes(element, value, fill=variable)) + 
geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]